# please find this guy's old account and merge

Tags: support

Please locate any possible account information for https://mathoverflow.net/users/44949/m-shahryari  and merge into the current account, should that be possible. he had assumed that things went wrong because of FaceBook; who knows? Anyway, I told him at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158444/example-of-non-commutative-ring-of-characteristic-5 that i would post a request on Meta and then put a link back at that question.

Comment: thank you, you asked it before me, I hope some one can help to merge both accounts of mine.

Comment: @M.Shahryari, maybe. It probably depends on the exact reason(s) your earlier account became inaccessible to you.

Comment: @M.Shahryari, there is now an "answer" to this by moderator Todd Trimble, who successfully located your earlier account and has started the process of merging it into your current account.

Comment: @M.Shahryari, final note, now we go back and forth between MO Main and Meta by clicking on the upper-left word StackExchange, which then shows you a choice of pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just put in a request to merge 29488 into 44949, with the latter to be made the permanent profile. The request should be processed in a day or two.

Update: apparently the merge has now been completed. (It's amazing how cumbersome the process actually is.)

Comment: Cool, thanks. We used to have a fixed "sticky" meta thread for merge requests that was always one of the top four or five, I guess it is not so easy to implement that in the stackexchange setup.

Comment: @WillJagy it could be made a [meta-tag:faq], which is the not-quite-analogue of a sticky thread. (It is however not quite clear to me this is still so useful. On the old MO the site moderators could do this and this was a/the way to contact them about this; now this has to be handled by SE staff and they set up a way that is documented in the help center http://mathoverflow.net/help/merging-accounts )

Comment: @quid, then i guess it all fits; not as frequent now, harder to do, we will just have requests one by one then.

Comment: @Todd Trimble: thanks, I didn't know that it is possible to merge both accounts, I am thankful of you and Will Jagy.

Comment: We could use chat for this sort of thing a bit more efficiently. Just paste the links there, then @timpost - please merge ^^^ - that's sufficient enough for me if it works for you.

Comment: @TimPost Definitely works for me. In fact, a relief -- thanks. :-)